# Ruby objects without 'to_s'

Tags: ruby

Are there any objects in ruby that don't respond to `to_s`?

The question isn't meant to ask whether it is possible to create one, which I know can be done by `undef_method`. Feel free to explain details, including caveats of undefining.

Comment: This is an incomplete and overly generalized answer so I am posting it as a comment instead. In a pretty standard situation, where most of the things you use are Model's the answer is no, however, as you have also implied in your own question, it is ridiculously easy to construct something that would not support it. Almost everything in Ruby is an array, so a string representation is always possible. If you would actually want to do that is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `BasicObject` class does not define a `to_s` method, so any instance of that class would not have a `to_s` method.

Comment: `BasicObject` should be used if you want to create a class from scratch, just make sure that you don't need any of the features we expect in standard classes.

Answer (score 0):

We should never specialize a subclass, since the subclass would not attend to the parent expectation anymore, have a look in the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: That doesn't answer the main question, but that is definitely what I thought of when asking for additional details, so thank you of course!

Comment: We have a semantic detail here :)  All classes in ruby inherits from `Object` by default (you have to explicitly inherit from `BasicObject` to avoid the default parent). So the answer to "Are there any Objects in ruby that don't respond to to_s?" is no :) (`BasicObject`s are not `Object`s but the other way around is true :) )

Comment: The term object is ambiguous in the context of Ruby. Under the first sense, it means (an instance of) the `Object` class, and is usually written not as "an object" but as "(an instance of) Object", in capitals. In the other sense, it means what object means in object oriented programming, and that includes instances of the `BasicObject` class as well. You rewrote the OP's writing "Are there any **objects** ..." to "Are there any **Objects** ..." (bold added by me), but that is your trick. Perhaps you already noticed that the OP meant object in the second sense, not the first.

Comment: @sawa You'd better look at the question's revision history.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Jonas' comment was right.